# With mozilla/TTS are other pre-trained model voices available?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, rasa

If you follow this article https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-build-a-voice-assistant-with-open-source-rasa-and-mozilla-tools/

it will have you download an 80MB file from:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GU8WGix98WrR3ayjoiirmmbLUZzwg4n0

called `best_model.pth.tar`

and using https://github.com/mozilla/TTS

you get the "sara" voice (which is very impressive)

Are there other best_model.pth.tar files out there with other pre-trained voices? Similar to CSS themes where you can download some or free, for pay or a really good one, do we have a pre-trained TTS model directory somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

You can choose from any of the available pretrained models on the [TTS](https://github.com/mozilla/TTS/wiki/Released-Models) repo. Some models provide a better audio quality than the one currently used in the blogpost. The process of using other models should be the same as the one covered in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `tts-server` and `tts` endpoints on console after `pip install TTS`.

`$ tts --list_models` will give you all the released models with some meta info. You can choose the one you like.